# circular dependency between two python libs

Tags: python-3.x, embedded-linux, opkg

I'm trying to set python3-pillow on an embedded linux.
I installed opkg and, so far, it worked when I used it to install several .ipk

When I try to install my python3-pillow_8.3.2-r0_cortexa72.ipk it indicates several requirements, so I install the corresponding .ipk until I reach a dependency on python3-crypt

When I try to install it I get the following

```
/var/tmp# opkg install python3-crypt_3.9.9-r0_cortexa72.ipk 
 *   - nothing provides python3-math needed by python3-crypt-3.9.9-r0.cortexa72
```

As I have done so far, I get the python3-math ipk and try to install it, then I get

```
/var/tmp# opkg install python3-math_3.9.9-r0_cortexa72.ipk  
 *   - nothing provides python3-crypt needed by python3-math-3.9.9-r0.cortexa72
```

Here is the problem, both libs depend on each other ???
I tried to get additional information on each lib:

```
:/var/tmp# opkg info python3-crypt_3.9.9-r0_cortexa72.ipk 
Package: python3-crypt
Version: 3.9.9-r0
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libcrypt2 (>= 4.4.25), libcrypto1.1 (>= 1.1.1o), python3-core, python3-math, python3-stringold
Recommends: ca-certificates, openssl
Status: unknown ok not-installed
Section: devel/python
Architecture: cortexa72
Maintainer: Poky <poky@lists.yoctoproject.org>
Source: python3_3.9.9.bb
Description: Python basic cryptographic and hashing support
 Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly and
 integrate your systems more effectively.


:/var/tmp# opkg info python3-math_3.9.9-r0_cortexa72.ipk  
Package: python3-math
Version: 3.9.9-r0
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), python3-core, python3-crypt
Status: unknown ok not-installed
Section: devel/python
Architecture: cortexa72
Maintainer: Poky <poky@lists.yoctoproject.org>
Source: python3_3.9.9.bb
Description: Python math support
 Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly and
 integrate your systems more effectively.
```

both depend on each other ... so I cannot install any.
Is there a workaround ?

my current python3 version is 3.9.9

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a bit surprised, but installing both at the same time solves the problem !

I just needed to install python3-stringold first

```
root@raspberrypi4-64:/var/tmp# opkg install python3-math_3.9.9-r0_cortexa72.ipk python3-crypt_3.9.9-r0_cortexa72.ipk 
Installing python3-crypt (3.9.9) on root
Installing python3-math (3.9.9) on root
```